# Black borders around content of site - site content window does not fill up Chrome window

Tags: google-chrome, browser, zoom, margins, border

When I open WhatsApp I see these black borders around. One time I got pretty frustrated with some code, and then pressed a lot of keys on the keyboard at the same time and this happened. How would I revert that?

Note that the zoom level displayed in chrome is 100%. I pixelated the content of the screenshot for privacy reasons.

WhatsApp black borders:

[image: WhatsApp black borders]

Comment: Your browser looks to be in a "dark mode", are the black borders not preferred in that case? If you have accidentally enabled a dark theme then the answer at https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2707959/how-can-i-turn-off-dark-mode-in-chrome?hl=en of "go to your chrome setting and select theme tab" might help.

Comment: Or you may have enabled a different viewport size by accident. Try https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/ and see if you can reset it that way.

Comment: @Mokubai I do not think it has to do with the dark theme. I know that I did not have the borders even with the dark theme on for a while; then the incident with "pressing multiple keys at once" happened and here I am

Comment: I realised that after the fact, hence my second comment.

Comment: It looks like you have some Chrome extensions enabled.  Does the problem still occur if you temporarily disable them, then restart Chrome?

Comment: @leeharvey1 yes it still does